# Refocus main window after closing OpenFileDialog in Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, openfiledialog

I have the user select a file using an OpenFileDialog. After the file is selected, and the dialog is closed, the main window is the last application when alt-tabbing. I want to have the main window regain focus and be on the foreground without having to alt+tab to it after closing the dialog window. Is this possible and if so how?

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Class1 c1;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        c1 = c1.Instance;
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        c1.Load(Content);

        c1.GetFile();
    }
}


public sealed class Class1
{
    private static Class1 _instance = null;
    private static readonly object _padlock = new object();

    private Class1()
    {
    }

    public static Class1 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Class1();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void GetFile()
    {
        string path;
        OpenFileDialog ofdSelectLayout = new OpenFileDialog();
        if(ofdSelectLayout.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = ofdSelectLayout.FileName;
        }
        //some code
    }

    public void Load(ContentManager content)
    {
        //Loading some textures
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought there would be an simple method for it. 
(like `Game.IsActive`, which only checks if the game is out of focus)

After a while, I've found this one around, you can place it in the method where the FileDialog is closing:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

Form myForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
myForm.Activate();
```

This however does use `System.Windows.Forms`, and that means that your game have to be Windows-exclusive for it. But if you're working in Windows Forms, you can see it as a workaround for now.